# Pass model data from one view to another view using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django and stuck on this problem. Basically page1 will ask the user for the name and address. I am doing this by using a model form. My model looks something like this

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first   = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    last    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone   = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    c_num   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    c_exp   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And my form on my first page looks like this:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['first', 'last', 'street', 'state', 'country', 'phone']
```

So I basically get the users information on the first page using the form. Then that updates my model but leaves the `c_num` and `c_exp` blank. Then on the second page I want to display the information that the user just entered and also prompt for the `c_xxx` properties. However, I am not sure how to update the current `Person` object. How would I search through all objects to find the current one the user is creating?

Comment: page 1 calls page 2?

Comment: Yes. page1 will ask for the user name, address, then you would click submit. Then page2 opens and displays everything entered and asks for the c_xxx information. Then when you save it updates that model in the database.

Comment: So you have to keep a track of your `Person.id` as `person_id` or similar somewhere so you can get it later by `Person.objects.get(id=person_id)` - check how Django ORM works and how to get later what you've saved so far and re-populate your form from a specific model.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good solution here would be redirect to `page2` with the person `id` from `page1` once the person created.

Something like this should work,

*in urlconf*

```
url('/page2/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/', page2(), name='page2')
```

*in page1*

```
return redirect('page2', user_id=new_person_id)
```